# Restricting access to internal websites with VPN

Tags: networking, cloud, vpn, private

I would like to implement the following project: I would like to build a network with various cloud servers, which should not be accessible from the outside (via the Internet). Access to the corresponding resources should only be possible when the visitor is logged into a specific VPN which is setup with Wireguard. On these cloud servers is then e.g. a Nextcloud or an internal website.

Now this is a new topic for me and I do not know exactly where to start here and how to achieve this. Does anyone here have suggestions or ideas where to start and what I have to do?

The following diagram shall visualize the project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host a website outside of the VPN network you could use a whitelist in the .htaccess file if you're hosting it with Apache2. You need to whitelist the ip address of the VPN in this case. I'm sure there are similar methods for other webservers.
If it's a server that is running internally, then you shouldn't have to do anything as this server is not port forwarded and only accessible through the VPN. Use the local ip address for this.